# Unable to hit breakpoints in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi controller with two HttpGet. I defined the routes as shown below. 
    when I call the methods with the link below, my breakpoint does not get hit.

http://localhost:49869/Api/Articles/SearchArticles/News

http://localhost:49869/Api/Articles/DefaultArticles/News

Is this link not correct?

```
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class ArticlesController : ApiController
        {

            // GET api/Articles/News
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("SearchArticles/{category}")]
            public IEnumerable<ArticlesDto> Get(string category)
            {
                IEnumerable<ArticlesDto> articlesByCategory = null;
                try
                {
                    if (category == null)
                    {

                    }

                   articlesByCategory = _articlesrepository.Find(category);               
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }

                return articlesByCategory;
            }


            // Get api/Articles/News
            // Pull default articles by category data
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("DefaultArticles/{category}")]
            public IEnumerable<ArticlesDto> GetDefault(string category)
            {
                IEnumerable<ArticlesDto> defaultArticlesByCategory = null;
                try
                {
                    if (category == null)
                    {

                    }

                    defaultArticlesByCategory = _articlesrepository.FindDefault(category);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //return BadRequest(ex.Message);
                }

                return defaultArticlesByCategory;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What does the browser show as the status code for those requests?

Comment: I am getting a 404 not found

Comment: change `[Route("api/[controller]")]` to `[RoutePrefix("api/Articles")]`

Comment: I am stil getting the 404 not found